# Are book recommendations questions allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I am looking for books where magic is commonplace (kind of like the Darkblade trilogy).

I know other Stack Exchange sites don't allow questions like that, but some have more relaxed rules than others.

If I ask my book recommendation question here, am I off topic?

Comment: Related: [Are “recommend me” questions allowed?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26/21267), [Should we revise our book recommendation policy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/764/21267), and [What is a good site for book recommendations?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1080/21267)

Comment: @Mooz The first of those questions is from so long ago that they *were* allowed back then, the second has no clear consensus, and the third is also severely out of date. A better dupe target would be [this definitive scope question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic); it might be slightly out of date, but much less so than the ones you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

### Not on the main site

One of the reasons to close a question specifically says:

> Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they
>   do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about
>   people's favorites in chat.

However, as indicated in that close reason, you can ask for recommendations in chat.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, they're not allowed. Straight from our [list of off-topic questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Reading or viewing recommendations: I liked X, what should I watch next?

But, you can always visit our one of our chat rooms for questions like these!

[Mos Eisley, or general chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)

[The Nexus, a fantasy-topic room chock-full of recommendations](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38833/the-nexus-fantasy-discussion)

[SFF On-topic chat, where discussion is just about Sci-fi and Fantasy, not the real world!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42263/sff-on-topic-chat)